# Определение улицы по координатам. WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps

Получаю данные с gps (широту и долготу).

Как их привязать с картами (google/yandex)?

Хочу получить название улицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Bing - How to Reverse Geocode a Location to an Address on Windows Phone 7](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/12/how-to-reverse-geocode-a-location-to-an-address-on-windows-phone-7/)
- [Google - Using Reverse Geocoding to Find an Address](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2011/06/22/making-a-reverse-geocoding-to-find-an-address.aspx)
- [Google - обратное геокодирование](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru#ReverseGeocoding)

Comment: благодарю.